# Bash parallel pipelined a for loop

Tags: bash, loops, parallel-processing, pipelining

I would like to know if there is a way to execute the body of the loop as soon as my generator has emited `IFS`. The default behaviour is for bash to slurp the loop and then execute it.

Take this code:

```sh
time for i in $(echo 3; sleep 2; echo 1); do sleep ${i}; done
```

It runs in 6s.
Because bash first execute `echo 6; sleep 2; echo 1` fully and slurp the input.
And then once 2s are spent here and the `echo 1` finished it follows it with the body of the loop.
Executing `sleep 3` and then `sleep 1`.

What I would expect is for it to run in 4s because:

- first `echo 3` is executed, triggering `sleep 3`.
- while `sleep 3` execute the `sleep 2; echo 1` code has time to run.
- when `sleep 3` finishes, the body of the loop is free again and `sleep 1` executes.

Note I don't want `& done`, I want a single body of my loop executed at one time, just pipeline the generator + loop execution.

You might think that `& do` does it (as it would be unambiguous vs `& done`), but not it doesn't, it fails with a syntax error.

Note I know I can do this with `xargs -P` or gnu-parallel but I would like to know if this is possible to do with loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I've just found it, still posting.
To have this behaviour, you must use the `while` loop with `read`.
The equivalent to my earlier for loop is this:

```sh
time (echo 3; sleep 2; echo 1) | while read i; do sleep ${i}; done
```

Correctly execute in 4s.